# Difference between @ and . amend in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have been reading a bit about [@](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/) amend on the KX wiki, which states:

> `@` (amend)
>
> Syntax: `@[x;i;f]`
> Syntax: `@[x;i;f;a]`
> Syntax: `@[x;i;f;v]`
>
> Functional amend Where
>
> `x` is a list (or file symbol, see Tip)
> `i` is an int vector of indexes of `x`
> `f` is a function
> `a` is an atom in the domain of the second argument of `f`
> `v` is a vector in the domain of the second argument of `f`

Messing around with both `@` and `.`, which seems to act similarly, I tried using an empty list in place of the indices and found that each treats it differently:

```
q)a
1 2 3
q)@[a;();+;100]
1 2 3
q).[a;();+;100]
101 102 103
```

It seems that with `@` using `()` equates to 'no indices' and with `.` it equates to 'all indices'. Why are such contrasting behaviours seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference can be down to the level of nesting both amends work with. `.` is for multiple levels of nesting and `@` for a single level (a list). By using `enlist` with the indices when using `.` we nest the indices and get the same output for a simple list like `a` you have provided:

```
q)a
1 2 3
q)@[a;();+;100]
1 2 3
q).[a;enlist();+;100]
1 2 3
q)@[a;(::);+;100]
101 102 103
q).[a;enlist(::);+;100]
101 102 103
q)@[a;1 2;+;100]
1 102 103
q).[a;enlist 1 2;+;100]
1 102 103
```

Using `()` with `.` is equivalent to the enlisted null function `(::)`.

It should be noted that this relationship holds true for complex lists:

```
q)show m:3 cut 1+til 9
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
q)@[m;1 2;+;100]
1   2   3
104 105 106
107 108 109
q).[m;enlist 1 2;+;100]   / nest with enlist
1   2   3
104 105 106
107 108 109
q).[m;(1 2;::);+;100]     / nest with null func
1   2   3
104 105 106
107 108 109
```